# prepend a string to htmlstring

Tags: c#, html

I want to prepend a string to a htmlstring in c#. The following is the valid html string in a variable

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<head>
<style> body{ font-family: verdana;  font-size: 10pt; } </style>
<title>dfdf</title>
           </head>
            <body>
            some body
            <br/>
            <br/><br/>
            </body>
```

displays 'some body' when html is rendered.

But I want to prepend with some additional text to the contents displayed by html so the output would be like

```
additional text

some body
```

concatenation of strings like below is not a valid html

```
var str = "additional text" + htmlString;
```

How to prepend a string to make it valid html string in c#? Or should I look for body tag using regex and prepend?

Comment: Put the whole thing in a StringBuilder.  Find the index (in the string) where you you want to do the insert (say, right after `<body>`) and insert the string.  Then call `ToString` on the StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var htmlString = "Your html string";
var prependValue = "additional text or html string";

htmlString = htmlString.Replace("<body>", "<body>" + prependValue);
```

This is a way basic method, but it should solve your problem.